# Deleted WordPress pages still online

Tags: php, wordpress

I deleted some pages on my wordpress admin platform (placed them in the trash AND deleted them definitely) but they are still accessible online. Besides, Google is still referencing them : here is the big problem.

Could someone help me to delete those pages from the web, or at least from the google search engine ? 
Thanks

Here is an example of a page I deleted and still online : https://lesmiraculeux.com/index.php/boutique/

I have already deleted the pages and they are not appearing anymore on my wordpress dashboard, neither on all the pages, nor on the trash.

Delete those pages

Comment: That page isn't visible where I am. Deleting pages is not instant when it comes to Google.

Comment: Please visit the help center to learn about asking on-topic questions here on SO.  Also, you should educate yourself on how search engine caching works - you're making an almost impossible request.

Answer (score 0):

The pages are already deleted...
Reasons why you still see them sometimes..

1 - Any caching plugin that might be installed on your wordpress or default wordpress catch(if any)...try removing all catch files...you can do it through settings of that particular plugin..

2 - Your browser sometimes gets confused by number of reasons and shows the old result on a specific URL although things have been changed there... try restarting your browser...clearing cookies history and other temporary files...in some cases restarting you pc will do the job.